# Zoom issue in webbrowser windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, browser, zooming, windows-phone

I am developing an advertisement in my application. I showed the advertisement in the webbrowser correctly. Now when double click on the webbrowser the content is zooming, But I want to programatically zoom the content of the webbrowser. (Want to zoom the content in webbrowser when the application launches, not double clicked by the user). How can I zoom the webbrowser content programatically ?..Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly supported by the `WebBrowser` control. However, you *might* be able to make this work by digging around in the internals of the control. I recently published a blog post which looked at [suppressing pinch and double-tap zoom interactions](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/). This was achieved by inspecting the visual tree of the `WebBrowser`:

```
\-WebBrowser
  \-Border
    \-Border
      \-PanZoomContainer
        \-Grid
          \-Border (*)
            \-ContentPresenter
              \-TileHost
```

Then handling interactions on the indicated Border (*). You might be able to find a way to emulate interactions in order to cause the browser to zoom.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the content being loaded in WebBrowserControl, you may consider adding this meta to the source.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480,user-scalable=no"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What Colin said is right, you cannot otherwise capture any manipulation events. But here on changing the margin of the webBrowser control you can see the zoom. So you need not take so much of work. So you can programmatically control the zoom to some extent. And if you need the zoom to be more specific to certain area of the web page, I suggest you to go for working on javascript. I am not sure if you can do with the sdk we have.

If you want to disable the zoom on user click what Apurv said works, but it gives a weird effect on double clicking. If you are not happy with that you will need some work arounds.